# I found this error while compiling the solidity code

Tags: node.js, solidity, ethers.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'ethers'
Require stack:

- D:\Blockchain\deploy.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\Blockchain\deploy.js:1:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\Blockchain\deploy.js' ]
  }

---

can anyone help me to find the solution to this error?

---

Comment: Please, can you add more information about your error?

Comment: This error arrives in the deploy.js file it says that some packages like stack. The package that i used is ether.js and fs  here is code